# de Moivre's Formula for Odd $n$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I am trying to show that: $$(\sin(\theta) +i\cos(\theta))^n = \begin{cases} &\sin(n \theta) + i \cos(n\theta) & \quad \text{when $n = 4m+1$}\\ -&\sin(n \theta) - i \cos(n\theta) & \quad \text{when $n = 4m+3$} \end{cases} $$

The hint that I am given is to use the fact that $\sin$ and $\cos$ are the same if you translate one horizontally by $\pi/2$ radians, but I am not sure how this helps. Any hints, or solutions, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same **hint** in different phrasing:
$$ \sin(\theta) + i\cos(\theta) = \cos(\pi/2-\theta) + i\sin(\pi/2-\theta) = e^{i(\pi/2-\theta)} $$

Alternatively, you can start by noting
$$ \sin(\theta) + i\cos(\theta) = i\bigl(\cos(-\theta)+i\sin(-\theta)\bigr) $$

Comment: This helps me to understand why the order of the $\sin$ and $\cos$ terms are swapped in comparison to the way de Moivre's Formula is generally written, but I don't see where to go after applying this identity, or how the form of $m$ comes into play. Is there another trig identity that I should be using? I tried using the formula for $\sin(a+b$ but that got me nowhere.

Comment: @openset: In the latter form, raise $i$ and $\cos(-\theta)+i\sin(-\theta)$ to the $n$th power separately, and use the normal De Moivre formula.